# Is it tracking progress of .loadTransferable(type:completion:) broken? It seems the returned progress class isn't updated

Tags: swift, key-value-observing

The .loadTransferable method returns a progress object (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/photospickeritem/4030160-loadtransferable)

It seems the progress class returned from the loadTransferable method does not update properly.
In the below example, I've added a timer to observe the progress object since KVO doesn't fire, and it's unchanging

```
private func onSelection() {
    guard let item = self.selection else {
        return
    }
    
    self.progress = item.loadTransferable(type: Data.self) { result in
        /// ...
    }
    
    self.observeProgress()
}

private func observeProgress() {
    guard let progress = self.progress else { return }
    let _ = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.1, repeats: true) { timer in
        print(progress)
        
        if progress.isFinished {
            timer.invalidate()
        }
    }
}
```

Logs:

`<NSProgress: 0x600002c2d300> : Parent: 0x0 (portion: 0) / Fraction completed: 0.0000 / Completed: 0 of 0`

The above log repeated as the timer fires

Comment: according to this: 
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/photospickeritem/4030159-loadtransferable
Progress returns nil if the system can't find a supported type. What are the supported types though?